# Angular2 RC6 reseting formGroup does not reset view values on radio buttons

Tags: angular

Working on RC6 I have a form with formControls that are bind to radio buttons. When I use reset() method on a formGroup the state of those radio buttons is reseted to null, which is ok. However the last radio is still selected.

Steps to reproduce:

1. I have the following formGroup

   ```
   this.form = formBuilder.group({
       email: ['', Validators.compose([
           Validators.required,
           emailValidator
       ])],
       sex: ['', Validators.required],
   });
   ```
2. Here is the template code in pug:

   ```
           label.radio-inline
               input(type='radio', value='male', [formControl]="form.controls['sex']")
               |  Male
           label.radio-inline
               input(type='radio', value='female', [formControl]="form.controls['sex']")
               | Female
   ```
3. I select male in my form.
4. I execute this.form.reset();
5. The form is now in untouched state and all validators are back to invalid as they suppose to be, however male radio button is still selected.

Expected result is that radio button should not be selected at this point because I reseted my form.

Here is this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VDfq8N

Comment: Please post the code that allows to reproduce.

Comment: Steps to reproduce added